# React Native App Crashing On The Emulator

Tags: crash, react-native

I don't get any errors on the app, it builds without an error, But the app crashes on the emulator all the time

[This is the message I get on my Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znMkm.png)

[App running on CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5eQO.png)

[Node Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rmsy.png)

Comment: It builds and gets a runtime error. Did you try to run it with android studio? If yes does it show any exceptions in the console?

Comment: I tried running it with android studio, but still the app crashes